# Referencing a PCL (Portable Class Library) from a Xamarin Mono for Android project

Tags: mono, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am using Mono for Android to create an Android application.

I'd like to reference some other library i've written in this project (Compiled as a portable class library).

Whenever i attempt to do so, i get an error saying: **"The current project does not support references to Portable Library projects.".**

Is there any way to overcome this?

Referencing the compiled project output works just fine.

Answer (score 9):

Check out [this post by Stuart Lodge](http://slodge.blogspot.com/2012/12/cross-platform-winrt-monodroid.html) on using PCLs across various platforms, including Mono for Android. It goes through the different steps you need to take to get it working properly, as well as numerous problems you might run into along the way.